# How to define function that maps different types of objects to one type

Tags: typescript

```
type ObjectA = {
  id: number;
  x: string;
  y: string;
  z: string;
}

type ObjectB = {
  id: number;
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

type Objects = (ObjectA | ObjectB)[]

type MappedObject = {
  id: number;
  a: string;
  s: string;
  d: string;
}

type MapFn = (obj: Objects) => MappedObject[];

const mapObjectA: MapFn = (obj: ObjectA[]) => obj.map(el => ({
  id: el.id,
  a: el.x,
  s: el.y,
  d: el.z
}));

const mapObjectB: MapFn = (obj: ObjectB[]) => obj.map(el => ({
  id: el.id,
  a: el.a,
  s: el.b,
  d: el.c
}));
```

In my example above, it will complain about lack of compatibility between ObjectA and ObjectB in both functions despite me explicitly passing the objects it's supposed to handle. Intuitively, it feels like TypeScript should be able to distinguish between the two objects when necessary.

> Type 'Objects' is not assignable to type 'ObjectA[]'.
> Type 'ObjectA | ObjectB' is not assignable to type 'ObjectA'.
> Type 'ObjectB' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectA': x, y, z.

What is a better, TypeScript-appropriate way of approaching this problem? I feel I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about unions.

If I pass both objects as parameters to the functions, it would probably work as long as I add checks for the keys I want to return, however, that quickly turns ugly if you have many objects to map.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `MapFn` type? What are you going to use it for, vs. just defining the functions? Since the functions don't know how to handle anything but the one kind of list they know now to handle, it's not clear how the `MapFn` type is useful.

Comment: One confusing thing about your question is that the `ListA`, `ListB`, and `MappedList` **aren't** lists. They're just objects. It's tricky to reason about the code when the names are misleading like that.

Comment: MapFn is to parse different types of objects from different sources into one common one to use elsewhere.

Comment: But how would you *use* it? Since you're going to assign one specific type of function to it, which can only handle one kind of list? Are you always going to pass a mapping function and the kind of list it can handle together, as a unit?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question to use the `Object` terminology from below to remove confusion

Comment: I don't understand the use case; either: you've built two inappropriate `MapFn` implementations, since `MapFn` says it can accept any array whose elements are `ObjectA` or `ObjectB`; it doesn't care, while your implementations certainly do care which one they receive; or: your `MapFn` isn't the right type, in which case we need to see usages beyond assigning `mapObjectA` and `mapObjectB` to them.  In either case we need to see more code from you. Please [edit] the question to show what you want to do with `MapFn` objects one you have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `MapFn` as a union of the two (or more) types of functions you're going to assign to `MapFn` instances. But it's not clear how that type is useful, since the actual functions you plan to assign to it can only handle one kind of list.

But here's an example of that. In this, I've changed `ListA`, `ListB`, and `MappedList` to `ObjectA`, `ObjectB`, and `MappedObject` since they aren't lists. Here's the `MapFn` type:

```typescript
type MapFn =
    | ((list: ObjectA[]) => MappedObject[])
    | ((list: ObjectB[]) => MappedObject[]);
```

(You need the `()` around each function type to keep the TypeScript parser happy.)

All together:

```typescript
type ObjectA = {
    id: number;
    x: string;
    y: string;
    z: string;
};

type ObjectB = {
    id: number;
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
};

type MappedObject = {
    id: number;
    a: string;
    s: string;
    d: string;
};

type MapFn =
    | ((list: ObjectA[]) => MappedObject[])
    | ((list: ObjectB[]) => MappedObject[]);

const mapListA: MapFn = (list: ObjectA[]) =>
    list.map((el) => ({
        id: el.id,
        a: el.x,
        s: el.y,
        d: el.z,
    }));

const mapListB: MapFn = (list: ObjectB[]) =>
    list.map((el) => ({
        id: el.id,
        a: el.a,
        s: el.b,
        d: el.c,
    }));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AQSgXigbwLABQUxUAlgCYBcUAdgK4C2cEATgNyElQAe1AzsBakaAcw5ESIfoOFjOJAF7Sho8QF9xhUJFiIUwAEJZc84hWr0mrcVwCGy2TZJwHq01GSu5BDYS3hoAFlbMEhyeCRUY3wJMypaRmZ2d3soARVvLj4vJ2J49MdCXwJ-HWCwADEaLHcAHygACgaAG1IBagj9NABtAF0ASiwAPihysM7UPv66xpa24A69VAMp4dGQ8aXgKc0CZAB7GgEoBhCAGXm0anKq4zn23Uj0Vcwh91aBADpTsCaIZsGr0aMS4XHMUH+nwoABp3HZqJDuLDYqDshDmp8QMjQSR4pCFNiSGp+v1dgcjsATud5gZriFbth7gtHvoVgNhu95t8Qn8AWsGiCcWQ8RiYXCSKlIbZCTi0ZC4DLQSLPshFcTSUA)

Comment: Thanks! This does fulfill the intention I had. However, I was experimenting with something similar in an attempt to simplify the code.

*type MapFn<T> = (list: T[]) => MappedObject[];*

This works but doesn't restrict which kind of lists can be passed. So I wonder if the type can be more generalized and still restrict the type of objects that can be passed.

Comment: @ougkr - Sure, union types and generic types are often both solutions to a certain kind of problem. If you want to lock down that `MapFn` you could use an `extends` clause: `type MapFn<List extends ObjectA[] | ObjectB[]> = (list: List) => MappedObject[];` https://tsplay.dev/WoxZpw Note that I used an array type for the generic, so we restrict it to only arrays of specific objects. If we just did `type MapFn<T extends ObjectA | ObjectB> = (list: T[]) => MappedObject[];`, it would allow an input of `(ObjectA | ObjectB)[]` (that is, an array with a mix of different objects in it).

Comment: @ougkr - Note, though, that the generic version would allow passing in a list of objects that *extend* your originals, like this: https://tsplay.dev/mqxlRN If you want that, great, but you were talking about restricting it. The union approach doesn't allow that: https://tsplay.dev/w298VW

Comment: I don't understand what this version of `MapFn` is good for.  A union of functions is only callable with an intersection of its parameter types, so unless the input is `ObjectA & ObjectB` it's uncallable unless it's been narrowed by assignment or something.  It's hard to narrow a function by control flow analysis because there's nothing you can check at runtime to determine the difference between `(x: X) => Z` and `(y: Y) => Z`.  I think the OP's use case needs to be spelled out more; the error they're getting is completely expected and the way to fix it depends on code not shown yet.

Comment: @jcalz - Indeed, I asked the OP (twice) what the type was for. You might want to post the comment above on the question in hopes of getting a useful answer to that.

Comment: @jcalz The data from different origins need to be mapped in such a way (MappedObject) that makes it compatible with other functions in the code which expects MappedObject as input.

Comment: But the function `MapFn` as provided here is essentially unusable for your stated goal; unions of functions are usually indicative of a problem.  If you had provided a [mre] with code demonstrating what you intend to do with `MapFn`, you'd see that.  You might be looking for [this behavior](https://tsplay.dev/w29OVW), but since you've already accepted this answer I guess we might never know?  Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Are these two totally different types? I'm imagining they have some similarity since you want to map the types into a common one. In this scenario, a discriminator would help.

For example, a `Discount` type could be a `percent` or `amount` discount. An `AmountDiscount` would have an `amount` property no `percent`, where as `PercentDiscount` may have a `percent` property, but no `amount`.

```
interface AmountDiscount {
  id: string;
  amount: 10
}

interface PercentDiscount {
  id: string;
  percent: 5
}
```

Ideally, you want to be able to process all objects of type `Discount` regardless of `Percent` or `Amount`, and you want to do it in a type safe way.
By type safe I mean, you don't want a `Discount` type that has both `percent` and `amount` property and in one situation either property is `null`. The user of the type has to figure out which one is populated and could accidentally use `percent` or `amount` in the wrong situation.

One way to solve this is to use the `in` keyword to see if a specific property exists on an object.

[Link to example of using `in` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIFsD2BXcARYAZwR3GQG8AoZG5YAEwC5lCwpQBzAbmtri1xhmIbOgBG0HgF9KlUJFiIUABWhJ8REoIq8aDZq3Yhuu5AAc1EcMNESo02WACeF5AWKkwAFRcRCNAF40AQ0PbQAfZFUodTB3LXAeShIQVhYwbBgYZnjPHwtCAG0AXWQgwtMqWmq6JmQAcn5PXMF6gBpTaqbBZgBGACYAZlMpDuqqmr06%20osYqzjNT3bO2lnY5gBWEcpi2QB6PeQEOBB6sGQYYA5sKBQcc4B3AAs4c%20dXCEQn5HpF7SIAHSUA7ICAAN3mRyeEAQAGtOMhnhAwNCoKDgCjoOYoJhZs5QQAPIhgfz0TB%20U6PTBQWHIVEQIGsTIwAHoOBmAAUHN%20YWsbj%204HyfgAlGUAHw6ao8hJgAEMHjVYAwZAcgBE3XAqroIB%20ArAoomk2lnjl9AVk11vNlGrA5poUlBABtCChKisaCD6XQqdhHfRkLCQJgHshMaHfHR-Gt5kCLcgQQBJcA4%20jYJDIOChp7AKD%20953ZXGwRtZBOHD1R2O5CO4CwiCOpzIEAQCD%20k6YTFohDQuGxi1F8AA6PgbZSYVAA)

Here's how I would personally do it: checkout this sandbox.
Essentially have an `enum` that explicitly defines the different types you intend to map to a common type.
You have a base type that have this enum on it and any other shared properties between the distinct types you are mapping.
Then for each type to map from extend the base class, define the specific type it is, and any properties specific to the type. Combine the different types into a single union type of all the expected types you are expecting to map to.
Then define an array of that union type, use a `switch` or `if` statements to determine which `type` you are dealing with and map them to the common type. Here's an example of having a discriminator property, having a base type, extending it for more specific types & processing it using the union type. You should be able to extrapolate from that what you need to do. Feel to ask more questions.

[CodeSandbox with example](https://codesandbox.io/s/types-with-discriminator-lv235p?file=/index.ts)